# R: WMS map not showing up

Tags: r, leaflet, wms

I have this WMS layer:

http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=composition_bbaod550

I want to add it to a leaflet map but it is not showing up.
Here is my code:

```
library("leaflet")
library("sp")

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(0, 50, zoom = 1) %>%
  addWMSTiles("http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap", 
  layers = "composition_bbaod550", 
  options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE))
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT #1:**

Here is what the network requests look like from the developer console

[image]

**EDIT #2:**

Here is my code with IvanSanchez's suggestions. As you can see the proposed approach did not fix the problem

```
library("leaflet")
library("sp")

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(0, 50, zoom = 1) %>%
  addWMSTiles("http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/", 
  layers = "composition_bbaod550", 
  options = WMSTileOptions(token = "public",
                           srs = "EPSG:4326",
                           format = "image/png", 
                           transparent = TRUE))
```

Comment: I do not necessarily need to use leaflet. It can be a static plot because I just need to plot it on top of a background map.

Comment: Are you viewing the map in Rstudio preview window?

Comment: Yes, I'm viewing the map in RStudio preview window

Comment: The service endpoint to use is: `http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&`  The [request for capabilities](http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&token=public&) shows us highest version of WMS supported is '`version=1.1.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we make a GetCapabilities request to the WMS service as below, we can see that the highest supported WMS version is 1.1.1.  So your GetMap request for a version=1.3.0 WMS service will probably error.

http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

When I looked at the response it appeared to have some errors and indeed when I checked in my XML editor, there are many errors (so many that the log is greater the character limit allowed in this answer).

**WMS configuration errors:**

```
System ID: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Main validation file: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Schema: http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd
Engine name: Xerces
Severity: error
Description: Attribute "xlink:execution" is not allowed to appear in element "OnlineResource".
Start location: 44:17
End location: 44:54

System ID: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Main validation file: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Schema: http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd
Engine name: Xerces
Severity: error
Description: Unexpected element "SRS". The content of the parent element type must match "(Name?,Title,Abstract?,KeywordList?,SRS*,LatLonBoundingBox?,BoundingBox*,Dimension*,Extent*,Attribution?,AuthorityURL*,Identifier*,MetadataURL*,DataURL*,FeatureListURL*,Style*,ScaleHint?,Layer*)".
Start location: 97:8
End location: 97:11

System ID: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Main validation file: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Schema: http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd
Engine name: Xerces
Severity: error
Description: Unexpected element "SRS". The content of the parent element type must match "(Name?,Title,Abstract?,KeywordList?,SRS*,LatLonBoundingBox?,BoundingBox*,Dimension*,Extent*,Attribution?,AuthorityURL*,Identifier*,MetadataURL*,DataURL*,FeatureListURL*,Style*,ScaleHint?,Layer*)".
Start location: 122:10
End location: 122:13

System ID: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Main validation file: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Schema: http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd
Engine name: Xerces
Severity: error
Description: Attribute "multipleValues" is not allowed to appear in element "Extent".
Start location: 137:60
End location: 137:78

System ID: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Main validation file: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Schema: http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd
Engine name: Xerces
Severity: error
Description: Unexpected element "SRS". The content of the parent element type must match "(Name?,Title,Abstract?,KeywordList?,SRS*,LatLonBoundingBox?,BoundingBox*,Dimension*,Extent*,Attribution?,AuthorityURL*,Identifier*,MetadataURL*,DataURL*,FeatureListURL*,Style*,ScaleHint?,Layer*)".
Start location: 273:10
End location: 273:13

System ID: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Main validation file: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Schema: http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd
Engine name: Xerces
Severity: error
Description: Attribute "multipleValues" is not allowed to appear in element "Extent".
Start location: 288:60
End location: 288:78

System ID: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Main validation file: http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities
Schema: http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd
Engine name: Xerces
Severity: error
Description: Unexpected element "SRS". The content of the parent element type must match "(Name?,Title,Abstract?,KeywordList?,SRS*,LatLonBoundingBox?,BoundingBox*,Dimension*,Extent*,Attribution?,AuthorityURL*,Identifier*,MetadataURL*,DataURL*,FeatureListURL*,Style*,ScaleHint?,Layer*)".
Start location: 393:10
End location: 393:13
```

...

The SRS / LatLonBoundingBox / BoundingBox section should look something like below (structure, not content):

```
<SRS>CRS:84</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:27700</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:3034</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:3413</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:3857</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:4258</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:900913</SRS>
<LatLonBoundingBox minx="-10.8018" miny="49.5889" maxx="3.92104" maxy="61.1359" />
<BoundingBox SRS="CRS:84"
            minx="-10.8018" miny="49.5889" maxx="3.92104" maxy="61.1359" />
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:27700"
            minx="-235677" miny="-34616" maxx="827937" maxy="1.28234e+006" />
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3034"
            minx="2.5664e+006" miny="2.55843e+006" maxx="3.67848e+006" maxy="3.94271e+006" />
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3413"
            minx="1.79406e+006" miny="-3.77262e+006" maxx="3.43831e+006" maxy="-2.09742e+006" />
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3857"
            minx="-1.20245e+006" miny="6.37538e+006" maxx="436488" maxy="8.6571e+006" />
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4258"
            minx="-10.8018" miny="49.5889" maxx="3.92104" maxy="61.1359" />
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326"
            minx="-10.8018" miny="49.5889" maxx="3.92104" maxy="61.1359" />
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:900913"
            minx="-10.8018" miny="49.5889" maxx="3.92104" maxy="61.1359" />
```

So the service is definitely not configured correctly, and this is probably the root cause of any problems you are having.

Comment: Many thanks for digging into this, I have let the maintainer of the service know. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** include the `version` nor the `request` parameters in the base WMS URL. These are added internally by Leaflet. Leaflet expects a *base* WMS URL, as explained in http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html.

So instead of

```
  addWMSTiles("http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap",
```

Do

```
  addWMSTiles("http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/?token=public&",
```

Also, quoting from the [Leaflet WMS tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html):

> `L.TileLayer.WMS` has extra options, which can be found in [Leaflet’s API documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tilelayer-wms-option). Any option not described there will be passed to the WMS server in the getImage URLs.

So you can actually do

```
  addWMSTiles("http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/", 
  layers = "composition_bbaod550", 
  options = WMSTileOptions(token = "public", format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE))
```

If this fails, use the developer console in your web browser (press F12) and see the network requests. How do the requests to the WMS look like?

---

Edit:

After a tiny bit of debugging, it seems that the WMS server is responding with:

```
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "/static/frontend/contrib/exception_1_1_1.dtd">

<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException code='InvalidSRS'><![CDATA[
Unsupported projection 'EPSG:3857'
]]>

</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

This means that the WMS server is not capable of outputting images which fit the default map projection for Leaflet.

If you want to use this WMS server, you'll have to check the list of supported map projections from its `GetCapabilities` document, and use Proj4Leaflet to make the map use a projection different than the default.

Do read:

- http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html#notes-to-gis-users-of-wms-services (Leaflet using a different map proj)
- http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_wms.html (How to see the capabilities of a WMS using QGIS)
- https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/inst/examples/proj4Leaflet.R (examples of Leaflet for R with custom map projs)

I'm sorry there's no straightforward answer; you'll have to do a bit of work and learning about projections.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it did not work for me. Did it work in your case? I've edited my question to add a screenshot with network requests I see from the developer console.

Comment: I actually do know about projections, the layer is in lat/lon (EPSG:4326, which is supported by leaflet). I have tried to add that to the options but it is still not working.

Comment: IvanSanchez, I don't think this is answering my question and some of your suggestions seem misleading (proj4Leaflet.R is obsolete). Sorry but I'm going to downvote this!

Comment: No hard feelings :-) Unfortunately my expertise is in Leaflet, not in the Leaflet for R.